# Reference File relative to installed location

Tags: node.js

I have a node utility I am writing where I have `index.js` and `results.hbs` in the root of the project. I installed this utility globally using `npm link` but when I run it from anywhere other than the project folder it can't find `results.hbs`. How do I reference `results.hbs` relative to the installed location rather than cwd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference any file relative to a library. So, if your library is called `mylib` you can find it's path like this

```
var mylibPath = require.resolve('mylib')
```

Then you can use that to reference any file in the library
Or if you need to just require something relative to a library you can do it like this

```
require('mylib/myfile')
```